# How can I make a trim rotate in SWIFTUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a RoundedRectangle and I want to make the trim rotate forever and make a nice animation from it.
[image: I added you this image here, so you can see what kind of trim I am talking about]

Tried to make a rotation effect and 3d rotation effect, but it didn't work

```
@State private var show = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.1))
            .frame(width: 195, height: 50)
        
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .trim(from: 0.25, to: 0.5)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round))
            .frame(width: show ? 50 : 200, height: show ? 200 : 50)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: show ? 90 : 0))
            .animation(.linear.delay(1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
                       value: show)
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .trim(from: 0.75, to: 1)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round))
            .frame(width: show ? 50 : 200, height: show ? 200 : 50)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: show ? 90 : 0))
            .animation(.linear.delay(1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
                       value: show)
        
        Text("title")
            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors),
                                            startPoint: .topLeading,
                                            endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
    }
    .onAppear {
        show.toggle()
    }
```

THis is my code. Made it move, but not the desired way... could be smoother and like two snakes going one after the other one

Comment: Instead of posting an image, please post the code you've already written to achieve the current behaviour. This will greatly increase the chance of a helpful answer

Comment: What is exactly the desired effect? Do you mean to make the segments go around the button (like say two snakes chasing each other)?

Comment: yes, just like two snakes

Comment: i didn't know how to say it, but these are the words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

---

Animate the changing of the trim offsets.  Since it is difficult to animate  past the boundaries of `0` and `1`, use `.rotation(Angle(degrees: 180))` to always stay within the boundaries of `0` and `1`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors = [Color.green, Color.blue]
    @State private var offset = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.1))
                .frame(width: 195, height: 50)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                .trim(from: 0.25 + offset, to: 0.5 + offset)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round))
                .frame(width: 195, height: 50)
 
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                .trim(from: 0.25 + offset, to: 0.5 + offset)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round))
                .rotation(Angle(degrees: 180))
                .frame(width: 195, height: 50)
            
            Text("title")
                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors),
                                                startPoint: .topLeading,
                                                endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.75).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                offset = 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Optimizing the code

Since the two "snakes" are identical except for the 180º rotation, we can code this with a `ForEach`:

```
ForEach([0.0, 180.0], id: \.self) { rotation in
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
        .trim(from: 0.25 + offset, to: 0.5 + offset)
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round))
        .rotation(Angle(degrees: rotation))
        .frame(width: 195, height: 50)
}
```

---

Comment: Solves my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: That rotation angle is legendary. I've had troubles with that before, amazing!